# MS Excel - Formatting Issue

Tags: excel

In MS Excel 2007 and 2010 I have a database of my sites locations where different locations are differentiated like AUG2345, AUG2346, AUG2347 and so on. When I enter AUG2345 in excel, it converts it to date immidiately. when i try to format the cell, it converts it to number however I want to keep the data as AUG2345, AUG2346 and so on. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use an apostrophe before the data, e.g. enter **'AUG2345**. The ' doesn't display in the cell itself, it simply tells excel to treat the data as text

Comment: Thanks Barry, great tip.  I know this but never have 'internalized' it.

Answer (score 1):

Before pasting, format the cell as `Text`.  Then paste.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Custom formatting and tell Excel you want it in this way, U can also change it to text or any other from there...